# Detect If Point of 2D Kernel Density Contains is Within a Certain Contour Level

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

I have constructed a 2D kernel density estimation and plot, an example of which looks like this:

```
library(ks)
mdf <- data.frame(x_values, y_values)
H <- Hpi(mydf)
fhat <- kde(x=mydf, H=H)

plot(fhat, display="filled.contour2", cont=seq(10, 90, by=10))
```

I an looking for a way to, given a contour level threshold and an x,y coordinate, to see if that given x,y falls within a particular contour level threshold.

As an example, if red denotes the regions which contains 10% of the total probability density and I give 5% as the threshold and a point lying within a red region, then the code would return TRUE.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: See what the help page says about the `eval.points` argument.  Note that the values returned by any KDE are a *density*, not a "mass," so I am concerned that you (or at least some readers) might misinterpret the meaning of your threshold. What do you understand it to represent?

Comment: Hi, I meant pobablity density, not mass. I have edited the question to reflect this. I have also hopefully made more clear in the question what the threshold would be: a point being located in a region that contains X percent or less of all the total probability density.